# Request variable not found in pluggable view

Tags: python, flask

I have a pluggable view defined as follows

```
class ListView(View):
    methods = ["GET", "POST"]

    def __init__(self, model, template_name="list_view.html"): 
        self.model = model           
        self.template_name = template_name

    def dispatch_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "GET":
           objects = self.model.query.all()
           return render_template(self.template_name, 
                               objects=objects)
        else:
           #do post request
```

I'm trying to create a pluggable view that'll handle both get and post requests. When I try the above, I get the following error however

```
NameError: global name 'request' is not defined
```

According to the Flask docs, the request should be present in the dispatch_request method, but it isn't in my case. I'm using Flask 0.10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` is always a global context variable; you need to import it in your module:

```
from flask import request
```

See the [Quickstart documentation on accessing request data](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#accessing-request-data); this is no different for pluggable views.

Comment: `request` gives you access to thread local data, yes. This is a bit of an over-simplification, and when using greenlets it's not thread-local but greenlet-local.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thank you!